# How to Isset a hyper link?

Tags: javascript, php, html

Is it possible to `isset()` a hyperlink?
I can't seems to make it work. I don't know what to do; I looked for many solutions, but they used `$_GET` or `$_REQUEST`. I don't want to use those.
I want to make it work like a submit button I am new to PHP and here is what I have done:

```
<?php

session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION['suser'])) {
    header("location:register.php");
    session_write_close();
    exit;
}

error_reporting(E_ALL);
include 'conectthis.php';
$suser = $_SESSION['suser'];
mysql_select_db("$suser", $con);
if (isset($_POST['select'])) {
    $result = "SHOW TABLES FROM $suser";
    $show = mysql_query($result) or die(mysql_error());
    if (!$show) {
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Create Master List First'); </script>";
        exit;
    }
}

?>



<body>
<hr />
<div align="center"><h1>Selection</h1></div>
<hr />
<form action="select.php" method="post">
<table width="50%" align="center">
<tr><td><a href="studrecord.php">Student Record </a></td><td><a name="select" href="fq1.php">First Period</a></td><td><a name="select2" href="fq2.php">Second Period</a></td><td><a name="select3" href="fq3.php">Third Period</a></td><td><a name="select4" href="fq4.php">Fourth Period</a></td><td><a name="summary" href="summary.php">Summary</a></td></tr></table>
</form></body>
```

I want a hyperlink to alert message something when the user have clicked a hyper link.

I hope you understand my English.

Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean by "isset" ?

Comment: Please be more specific when posting your question. It will make it more easy for us to help you. And btw, hearts do not have any influence on StackOverflow... We are not like that... haha

Comment: You can use the isset with an anchor tag

Comment: I hope `register.php` begins differently or you will end up in a redirect loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a shot in the dark, but is this what you want?

Show a message which is set through PHP.

```
<a href="#" onclick="return showMessage('<?php echo 'say hello'; ?>');">Click Me</a>


    <script type="text/javascript">
    function showMessage(message){
        alert(message);
    }
    </script>
```

Show a message using just JavaScript.

```
<a href="#" onclick="return showMessage();">Click Me</a>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    function showMessage(){
        alert('hello);
    }
    </script>
```

Comment: Maybe: if click hyperlink, add url parameter. Check with PHP if parameter (hyperlink for TS) isset, then display message. Just an idea;)

Answer (score 0):

This would be done with JavaScript via a `click` event. PHP would have no part in it.